# How do I insert eps into the latex?

Tags: matlab, latex, eps

I created .eps files from Matlab and trying to insert them into Latex.
I found the sample code on the website and follow them.
Below is the code that I wrote

I add

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

And then I wrote as follows

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{figures/result.eps}
\end{figure}
```

But the code doesn't work.

Any ideas on how to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{result}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Package pdftex.def Error: File `figures/result-eps-converted-
to.pdf' not found: using draft setting.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
...

l.117 ...cale=0.6]{figures/result}

And this is .log file

```
2021-09-07 16:43:29,426-0500 INFO  miktex-epstopdf.core - start process: mgs.exe -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dSAFER -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dMaxSubsetPct=100 -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -sOutputFile=figures/result-eps-converted-to.pdf - -c quit
2021-09-07 16:43:29,656-0500 FATAL miktex-epstopdf.core - Invalid argument
2021-09-07 16:43:29,656-0500 FATAL miktex-epstopdf.core - Function: fclose
2021-09-07 16:43:29,656-0500 FATAL miktex-epstopdf.core - Result: 22
2021-09-07 16:43:29,656-0500 FATAL miktex-epstopdf.core - Data: <no data>
2021-09-07 16:43:29,656-0500 FATAL miktex-epstopdf.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Stream\FileStream.cpp:68
2021-09-07 16:43:29,656-0500 FATAL miktex-epstopdf - Invalid argument
2021-09-07 16:43:29,656-0500 FATAL miktex-epstopdf - Info: 
2021-09-07 16:43:29,656-0500 FATAL miktex-epstopdf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Stream\FileStream.cpp
2021-09-07 16:43:29,656-0500 FATAL miktex-epstopdf - Line: 68
2021-09-07 16:43:29,692-0500 ERROR miktex-epstopdf - minor issue: It has been a long time since you have checked for MiKTeX updates.
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? What's the problem exactly? What exact commands did you use to generate the ".eps" files? Sometimes you need the `clip` option in `includegraphics`

Comment: Define "does not  work". Do you get any error message in the log file? If your tex distribution is not complete outdated, it should convert the eps automatically to a format it can include

Comment: Can you also make a compilable [mre] instead of the code fragment?

Comment: You should also leave out the file extension, latex will automatically pick up the format best suited for the engine you use.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I just saw an error message saying '! Package pdftex.def Error: File `figures/result-eps-converted-
to.pdf' not found: using draft setting.
See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.'

Comment: @Chang Please add a [mre] and the `.log` file to your question. If I had to guess I'd say your tex distribution might need an update

Comment: What tool do you use to build your LaTeX output? `latex`, `pdflatex`, something else? This issue has nothing to do with MATLAB, and might be better suited for https://tex.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: 1) don't use `epstopdf` if your tex distribution is up-to-date. That's a relict from the past when the conversation was not done automatically. 2) Unfortunately that's not the latex log file. It should be in the same folder as your .tex file with the same name.

Comment: 3) based on "It has been a long time since you have checked for MiKTeX updates." I still guess your tex distribution is outdated....

Comment: @CrisLuengo The engine is `pdflatex`, other engines would use another graphics driver file

Comment: If `pdflatex` is indeed the engine, export your MATLAB figures as PDF instead of EPS. 100% easier workflow.

Comment: I changed to Texmakers and now it works. Thanks for all the ideas.